# Manged Metadata term translations are mixed

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I have a serious problem with term translations on SharePoint Online Managed Metadata Service.

We use following languages:
1033 - english
1029 - czech
1031 - deutsch
1038 - hungarian
1045 - polish

After a while term translations are mixed and I see english words on polish translations, or even czech words on polish translations, everything is messed up.
Someone had similar issues with taxonomy? Any tips to diagnose this issue?